# Inserting current date and time in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to create a table in SQLite in which one of the field is for date, in which date and time of current instance should save. Which data type should I use?

I'm planning to use 'timestamp'. How to insert current timestamp value to the field? Also how to write content values for this date field?

Answer (score 79):

SQLite supports the standard SQL variables `CURRENT_DATE`, `CURRENT_TIME`, and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
INSERT INTO Date (LastModifiedTime) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

The default [data type for dates/times](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) in SQLite is `TEXT`.

`ContentValues` do not allow to use generic SQL expressions, only fixed values, so you have to read the current time in Java:

```java
cv.put("LastModifiedTime",
       new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
```

Comment: Selecting these three constants return values but the only way that I can get the time to not be off by six hours is with David Garoutte's answer above.

Comment: @GaryZ By default, SQLite dates are in UTC. If you expect them to be in your local time zone, your expectations are off. :-)

Answer (score 30):

```
INSERT INTO Date (LastModifiedTime) VALUES(DateTime('now'))
```

Use this [site](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for further reference.

Comment: is this insert current timestamp value?

Answer (score 5):

To get the current local(system) time, add the 'localtime' option:

select datetime('now', 'localtime');

Answer (score 1):

I'm using timestamps a lot in my app. For me the best way to keep the timestamp is to convert it in milliseconds. After that it is easy to convert it to any locale.

If you need the current time use System.currentTimeMillis().
Content values are easy to use, you just and field and value, like:

```
ContentValues ins_reminder = new ContentValues();
ins_reminder.put("REMIND_TIMESTAMP", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since SQLite 3.38.0, there is a `unixepoch()` function that returns UNIX timestamp in integer. Does the same thing as `strftime('%s')`.

References:

- [release log draft](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/releaselog/current.html)
- [check-in](https://sqlite.org/src/info/19c51b46e4095ee28badb10f4e08bbd330bda320c9a8806e93b8fc60ba211a2e)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i wanted to have a timestamp with fractions of a second.

- The [keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` has only a precision of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (see [docs DEFAULT clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#the_default_clause)).
- The function `strftime()` can return fractions of a second

#### Example to use `strftime()` in an `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (TimeStamp)  
       VALUES (strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%s'))
```

#### Comparison of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `strftime()`

```
SELECT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' as Timestamp_Command, 
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as TimeStamp_Precision,
       'only seconds'  as Timestamp_Comment 
UNION ALL           
SELECT 'strftime(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%s)' as Timestamp_Command, 
        (strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%s')) as TimeStamp_Precision,
        'with fraction of a second' as Timestamp_Comment
```

[image: Sqlite_Select_Current_Timestamp_vs_strftime]

#### Example to use it in c#

The following is based on [bulk insert in sqlite with ado.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/bulk-insert)

```cs
public static void InsertBulk(SqliteConnection connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
       var command = connection.CreateCommand();
       command.CommandText =
            @"INSERT INTO BulkInsertTable (CreatedOn, TimeStamp)
              VALUES ($createdOn, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%s'))";

       var parameter3 = command.CreateParameter();
       parameter3.ParameterName = "$createdOn";
       command.Parameters.Add(parameter3);  

       // Insert a lot of data
       // calling System.DateTime.Now outside the loop is faster
       var universalTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
       for (var i = 0; i < 15_000; i++)
       {
          parameter3.Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
          // faster 
          // parameter3.Value = universalTime;
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```