# Android Adding DATE (now) to SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime

Currently my SQLite database is working great, I have read up on various methods such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473325/inserting-current-date-and-time-in-sqlite-database) to achieve this, though currently I am having issues with setting up the Date constructor and also how to define the data for use in putting it to the database (and getting it back!)

So far I have used static final String to define my data variables, notsure which is the correct way to use Date.

I'm not concerned with the time, just the date the entry was created.

Below is my java class:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Stats {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "weight";
    public static final String KEY_WAIST = "waist";
    public static final String KEY_CHEST = "chest";
    public static final String KEY_LEGS = "legs";
    public static final String KEY_ARMS = "arms";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "statsDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "personalStats";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    private DbHelper ffHelper;
    private final Context ffContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ffDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_WEIGHT
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_WAIST + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_CHEST + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_LEGS
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ARMS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
                    + KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }

    public Stats(Context c) {
        ffContext = c;
    }

    public Stats open() throws SQLException {
        ffHelper = new DbHelper(ffContext);
        ffDatabase = ffHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public void close() {
        ffHelper.close();

    }

    public long createEntry(String weight, String waist, String chest, String legs, String arms) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
        Date date = new Date();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_WEIGHT, weight);
        cv.put(KEY_WAIST, waist);
        cv.put(KEY_CHEST, chest);
        cv.put(KEY_LEGS, legs);
        cv.put(KEY_ARMS, arms);
        cv.put("date_created", dateFormat.format(date));
        return ffDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_WAIST, KEY_CHEST, KEY_LEGS, KEY_ARMS, KEY_DATE };
        Cursor c = ffDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iWeight = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEIGHT);
        int iWaist = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WAIST);
        int iChest = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHEST);
        int iLegs = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LEGS);
        int iArms = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ARMS);
        int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iWeight)
                    + " " + c.getString(iWaist) 
                    + " " + c.getString(iChest) 
                    + " " + c.getString(iLegs) 
                    + " " + c.getString(iArms)
                    + " " + c.getString(iDate)+ "\n";

        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Obviously any time Date is mentioned is where I have attempted to add this extra functionality.

Comment: Where is the problem exactly? We don't succeed to insert the current date? Do you have any error logs?

Comment: the problem is I cannot enter the current date into my DB, I have imported the java.util class and I am in th process of tying a few different methods, was wondering if anyone knew the best way to do this based on my current code?

Comment: You should declare it as a date, not a text:
`KEY_DATE + " DATE NOT NULL);"`

And also change your format:
`dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: I am currently going through pulling the date from a datepicker and converting it to a String, then putting it to the database, is this recommended, personally i can't see it being a hinderance as I'm not using the date for any calculation...

Answer (score 0):

You may put date like string in database, but this string must have good format.
For SQLite it is:

```
YYYY-MM-dd
YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm
YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss
hh:mm
hh:mm:ss
hh:mm:ss.sss
```

Like Yoann write you can convert date to string with:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

String dateForinsert = dateFormat(new GregorianCalendar(2013, GregorianCalendar.MAY, 5).getTime());
```

"Now" you can set with:

```
String dateForinsert = dateFormat(new GregorianCalendar().getTime());
```