# insert date of record Sqlite3 database values (?, ?, ?, "Date()")?

Tags: javascript, express, sqlite, multer, body-parser

I am trying to append the date of an entry to my database, when the user has submitted there form. I have this working on table creation, but I can't seem to get it work for when the values are inputted.

Table Creation:

```js
  db.serialize(function() {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entry (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, level INTEGER, activity TEXT, meal TEXT, date DATE)");
    db.run("DELETE FROM entry");
    db.run("INSERT INTO entry (level, activity, meal, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
    4,"No", "Snack", Date('now', 'HH:MM'));
    db.run("INSERT INTO entry (level, activity, meal, date) VALUES (?, ?, ? , ?)",
    22,"No", "Takeaway", Date('now', 'HH:MM')); 
    db.run("INSERT INTO entry (level, activity, meal, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
    8,"Yes", "Snack", Date('now', 'HH:MM'));
    db.run("INSERT INTO entry (level, activity, meal, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
    2,"Yes", "Fruit", Date('now', 'HH:MM'));
   });
```

And then this is the code for when the user inserts the data:

```js
restapi.post('/addentry', upload.array(), function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body);
    db.run("INSERT INTO entry (level, activity, meal, date) VALUES (? , ?, ?, 'Date()')", req.body.level, req.body.activity, req.body.meal,
     function(error){
        if (error){        
            console.err(error);        
            res.status(500);      
            } else {        
               res.status(202);
            } res.end();    
    }); 
   
   });
```

I can't seem to get it to work, I have tried "Date()", but this causes errors.

Does anyone have any idea's on this?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT date('now');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting current date and time in SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473325/inserting-current-date-and-time-in-sqlite-database)

Comment: A description of `date()` and its arguments is here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html